# Build on real Device has error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

When I run on real device, it show error but it works fine on simulator. How can I solve this issue? please help me. thanks

```
 ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/alex/Desktop/FitnessApplication/RazerSynapseSDK.framework/RazerSynapseSDK, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/alex/Desktop/FitnessApplication/RazerSynapseSDK.framework/RazerSynapseSDK (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RzUser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in SignUpViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ForgotPassViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in UserInfoViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for "Undefined symbols for architecture"?

Answer (score 1):

Go to project ->build setting -> architecture and add armv6,armv7.

remove armv7s. Similarly for the target->build setting->architecture.

armv define family of instruction set being used.

Comment: In current app used standard architecter (including 64 bit) (arm7, arm7s, arm64). How can I add armv6,armv7?

Comment: The error on my question. When i run on simulator, it's ok but run on real device, it shows that error. I don't know why :(

Comment: armv defines the instruction set which is going to be used to run the binary on processor...simulator uses i386 so no error ...you remove every thin just add armv6 only see if it works

Comment: I just add amrv6 to Architectur and it shows error : Check dependencies

No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv6, VALID_ARCHS=arm64 armv7 armv7s).

Comment: cant be of more help from this distance sorry